# TCP client sends message only once and get stuck in loop

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client, embedded-linux

Requirement : I am using TCP client which will communicate with external TCP server. TCP server will not send any acknowledment about message received or not. TCP client has to send message periodically after certain duration.

I have one application(GPS manager app)  which reads GPS cordinates and publishes through mosquitto periodically after every 5 sec. I am subscribing that topic in my TCP sender APP. On message callback of that message in TCP sender app  , I need to send these details to TCP server (external). TCP server won't send any message to request GPS data.

I am able to connect with TCP server successfully. Also able to send data to server but only once. After sending data TCP sender app doesn't receives any messages sent by GPS manager app.

```
    int32_t SendToServer(ServerClientCfg_t st_TmpServerClientCfg, char *c8_PacketData)
    {
        //int opt = 1;
        int sock = 0;
        // int sent=0;
        int valread;
        int byte=0;

        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        //char *hello = "Hello from client";
        char buffer[1024] = {0};
        if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        {
            printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
            return -1;
        }

        //fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

        memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

        // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
        if(inet_pton(AF_INET, gst_DataSenderCfg.st_ServerClientCfg[0].pc8_HTTPServerURL, &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
        {
            printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
            return -1;
        }

        if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        {
            printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
            return -1;
        }

        while(1)
        {
            byte= send(sock , c8_PacketData , strlen(c8_PacketData) , 0 );
            printf("Bytes sent : %d\n",byte);
            printf("Count : %d  : Message sent from client :  %s\n\n",count,c8_PacketData);
            count++;
            sleep(1);
            break;              
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Expected result : TCP server should receive GPS data periodically after 5 sec.

Current result : Server is receiving data only once.

Comment: Just remove `break` from *while* loop.

Comment: result is same after removing break. Pls note SendToServer function will be called on every message_callback .

Comment: Anyway, why would you use a `while(1)` loop if you will always break it in the first iteration? Can you show the log output of the application (printf)?

Comment: You should close the socket when before you leave that function.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Instead of your GPS callback you might use a loop that calls your function. Without more code (and the logs) we cannot see if that function is even called a second time.